# C program: if statement within switch statement

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program that will switch between "modes". For example here are little snippet of the code:

```
int main()
{
int mode,input;
mode = 1;
   for(;;)
   {
   scanf("%d", &input);
      switch(input)
      case 1: 
         if(mode = 1)
         {
         //statements go here;
         mode = 2;
         }
         else
         {
         //statements go here;
         mode = 1;
         }
      break;
   }
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is get the program to switch between mode 1 and mode 2 by the input of the 1 button. However each time I press the number 1 key, it will only print the statements of mode 1 but won't switch to mode 2 and print out the statements for mode 2 if i press the number 1 button a second time. Is there something fundamentally wrong with my code?

*restriction: I must use the switch statements in the program.

Comment: typo?? `if(mode = 1)` or `if(mode == 1)`

Comment: To avoid these kind of problems, it is a good programming practice to keep constant values on the left side (ie., `1 == mode`).

Comment: Not a typo in the post, was a typo in the program. That was the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: @MadMaximus Since it's a single-character issue, it has good chances to be closed as "trivial typo". But the question itself was alright, the formatting was perfectly fine too. No need to introduce the question with a foreword about "new here, forgive formatting errors" ;)  If you notice a formatting error, you can edit your post with the little gray 'edit' button in the bottom left corner. Have fun learning C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test the value of a variable you need double equals:

`if(mode == 1)`

Comment: Oops duh. That fixed the problem. Thank you so much